# Azure Devops Pipeline Yaml: check if a stageList contains a particular task?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an extend template that takes a stageList parameter. I need to check if the stageList contains a checkout task so I can insert one if it's missing. This is because I am checking out another repo later on and the default action if no checkout is defined is to checkout self, but if different repo is checked out the self checkout needs to be made explicitly. I need to add this so if the consumer did not have a checkout in their original pipeline it will still checkout their code.

My template takes a stageList parameter:

```
parameters:
- name: buildStages
  type: stageList
  default: []
```

How do I check for the existence the checkout task? I inspected the yaml and see the following structure:

```
stages:
- stage: ''
  jobs:
  - job: ''
    steps:
    - task: 6d15af64-176c-496d-b583-fd2ae21d4df4@1
```

I attempted to check for the task with the containsValue function, but this approach is obviously incorrect as the resulting yaml file still has two checkout tasks.

```
stages:
- ${{ each stage in parameters.buildStages }}:
  - stage: ${{ stage.stage }}
    jobs:
    - ${{ each job in stage.jobs }}:
      - ${{ each pair in job }}:
          ${{ if ne(pair.key, 'steps') }}:
            ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}
        steps:
        - ${{ if not(containsValue(parameters.buildStages.stage.jobs.job.steps.task.value, '6d15af64-176c-496d-b583-fd2ae21d4df4@1'))}}:
            - checkout: self
        - ${{ job.steps }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found how to reference the arrays in the buildstages via this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/pipeline-decorator-context?view=azure-devops)

Solution:

```
steps:
- ${{ if not(containsValue(job.steps.*.task, '6d15af64-176c-496d-b583-fd2ae21d4df4@1')) }}:
    - checkout: self
      displayName: base-Checkout
```

Humorously, before I found that I did get this working by iterating through all the tasks and setting a variable to true if the checkout task was encountered. Happy to have found the article above and removed that code from my template.